# Click to hide/show hree level navigation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic HTML menu with three levels:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

On load, I would like for only the top level nav items to show. When a user clicks on a link, they will see the sub-menu. For, that I have:

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').toggle();
});
```

That works just fine.

```js
$('ul li a').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.sub-menu').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2.3</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">3.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3.2</a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">3.2.1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">3.2.2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">3.2.3</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">3.3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3.4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">4.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4.3</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that the sub-menus do not hide unless you click them again (toggle).

I would like for only one navigation item and it's sub menus to be showing at one time.

What I need is for every sub-menu that is not a child of the top level nav item that was clicked on to be hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start out showing only the top level menu, use this CSS:

```
ul ul {
  display: none;
}
```

To show only the appropriate submenu, see the comments below:

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
  $('ul ul').hide();                  //hide all ul children
  $(this).parents('ul').show();       //show all ul ancestors of the clicked anchor
  $(this).next('.sub-menu').toggle(); //toggle its submenu
});
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$('ul li a').click(function() {
  $('ul ul').hide();                  //hide all ul children
  $(this).parents('ul').show();       //show all ul ancestors of the clicked anchor
  $(this).next('.sub-menu').toggle(); //toggle its submenu
});
```

```css
ul ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Test 2a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test 2b</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test 2c</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 3</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Test 3a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test 3b</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Test 3b 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test 3b 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test 3b 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Test 3c</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test 3d</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 4</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Test 4a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test 4b</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test 4c</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, that is it. Thank you so much.